# Text in Torchlight on Linux disappear when leveling up

Tags: linux, torchlight

I have a bug in Torchlight Humble Bundle Linux. When I level up and want to select the upgrades the fonts of the whole screen change when it's run with `sudo` to blocks and when it's run without `sudo` they disappear.

[image]

As you can see the faces also disappear but this is a known bug and it doesn't change the game's playability. But the disappearing fonts are really annoying. How do I fix this?

I am using Linux Debian Wheezy 64 bit.

Comment: Why are you running a game under `sudo`?  That sounds very unsafe.  The Linux version unfortunately has unresolved graphical bugs.  Now that TL2 is out, good luck finding support.

Comment: Yeah I thought so that it would be hard to find help with it, but I use sudo because if I don't the sound doesn't work and there are a lot of other issues.

Comment: The permissions issues that `sudo` fixes are probably due to configuration problems (e.g. your user not being in the `audio` group), but I don't think those are related to the graphical glitches.  I've checked forums.runicgames.com myself but activity for Torchlight 1 is all but dead.  I'd guess that you should have the best luck with Ubuntu.  I run Debian stable and the graphical glitches are even worse, probably due to older graphics packages.

Comment: Well thank you for your information, but then it's easy, I'll stop playing the game.

Comment: Are you sure you got the latest version?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like whole font was wiped out of memory. I don't know if it helps but I found this on https://pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/Torchlight

```
Upgrade the kernel and/or reinstall fglrx-driver for AMD video cards
```

I was unable to find anything more. Hope it helps.